# Array Element Incomplete return - AJAX PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I was trying to return an array data on ajax call but the elements it return is incomplete

```
public function test(){
    
    $return = array('err' => true, 'msg'=> 'No Attachment Processed' , 'data' => '');
    return $return;
}
```

Above is the sample method i want to return, however, when i try to prompt it, it only return the elements shown in
[this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eFhiU.png)

Is anyone familiar with this?

```
 $.ajax({
        dataType : 'JSON',
        type : 'POST',
        url: 'main/test',
        beforeSend : function(){
        },
        success : function(r){
            alert(JSON.stringify(r));

        },
        error : function(e)
        {
            
        }
    });
```

This is the ajax parameters i used.

Comment: Your php code doesn't include the part where that data is actually send. I'm guessing that's a simple combo like `json_encode` & `echo` ? If its more complicated than that it may be stripping away empty values. -- another possiblity is that `data` is reserved on the JQuery side (i dont know if it is). I guess if i were in your shoes, the first thing i'd narrow down is to see what would change when you change the key `data` into `databcabcabcabc`; and likewise, what would happen if it was left as key `data` but with an actual value.

Comment: I have tested this and I get the complete data if I am just using something like `echo json_encode(['err' => true, 'msg' => 'message', 'data' => ''];`. So my guess is that you are doing something else which strips out the empty data field from the response before returning it. Please include the code where you actually send the data from PHP.